# Working with List<webdriver> java and c#

Tags: selenium, java, c#

In c# i always use

```
 `IList<IWebElement> SearchResult1 = Setup.driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("div.comma.line"));`
```

and i access the `SearchResult1`  by SearchResult1[0] or SearchResult1 [].
It allow me to click on the `SearchResult1[0]` too.

But how am i going to do this in Java.
I have this list and cant access the list by its index number.

```
List<WebElement> matches = TopLayer.findElements(By.tagName("li"));
matches[0]
```

Im getting an error.

Answer (score 2):

For list iterator use below loop

```
for ( WebElement we: matches ) { 
   //Do something 
}
```

or you can: `matches.get(0);` or `matches.get(1);` and so on

Answer (score 0):

Array can be access by its index like `matches[0], matches[1]` while List is a ordered collection in Java. To access or add elements in list by using `matches.get(index)` or `matches.add(value)` methods.

Refer how to use [list in Java](http://beginnersbook.com/2014/08/arraylist-in-java/)